# How to deploy node.js (with express.js api's) on real time server

Tags: node.js, npm-live-server

please anyone here who guid me i deployed nodejs on firebase(functions) and netlify(function with serverless-http). the issue is when i save the file to folder then was getting error and i studies from articles that need real time server with cloud hosting then can possible to save the file to the folder (with express-fileupload). please tell me what are the best options.(is droplet service on digitalocean better option?) can i save files to folder with droplet on digitalocean? anyone know/experienced ?

Comment: yes you can use digitalocean droplet and amazon ec2 for server and you can save any thing like your local server

Comment: you can check amazon ec2 it will give u free instance for your testing purpose.

Comment: if you want to use firebase then u have to store your files somewhere else like amazon s3

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/977/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-application-on-aws-ec2-server u can read this article for complete deployment process in ec2